# RealmSwift 3.1.0 armv7 support

Tags: ios, swift, realm, armv7

Today I updated `RealmSwift` version in my project to the latest one, and now I see that the build that I sent to AppStore does not support `armv7` architecture. Also, I received a message from Apple that some symbols have no corresponding slice in a binary. For my project I need to support `armv7` architecture. Am I right that RealmSwift supports `armv7` prior to version 3.1.0 only?

Comment: Same issue for me...

Comment: Based on the samples, `armv7` should still be supported by Realm: https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/b4d8d7c3c3fe97aaf7940a05b97d1458ea5e832f/examples/ios/swift/Simple/Info.plist#L27-L30

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I guess this plist was modified last time before RealmSwift 3.1.0 was released.

Comment: Tested with version 2.10.2 and same problem... What is your version compatible with armv7 ?

Comment: @FlorianMacLanglade RealmSwift 3.0.2 is OK for me.

Comment: This is very strange ! With 3.0.2 version I still get "No such module 'RealmSwift'" when I try to archive (not for debug build)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today I installed `RealmSwift` v.3.1.1 and I see that is works fine with `armv7` and `armv7s` devices. If you have the same problem as described in this question, just update `RealmSwift` from version 3.1.0 to 3.1.1.